# Правильно ли реализован паттерн Builder ? (Продолжение)

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, java

Выкладываю на рассмотрение вторую реализацию паттерна Builder.

**1) Абстрактный класс BaseCarBuilder.**

```
 public abstract class BaseCarBuilder {

    protected Car car;

    public abstract void buildBody();

    public abstract void buildColor();

    public Car getCar() {
       return car;
    }

   }
```

**2) Класс Car.**

```
public class Car {

    public final static String RED = "RED";
    public final static String BLACK = "BLACK";
    public final static String WHITE = "WHITE";
    public final static String SEDAN = "SEDAN";
    public final static String CABRIOLET = "CABRIOLET";
    public final static String LIMOUSINE = "LIMOUSINE";

    private String name;
    private String body;
    private String color;

    public Car(String name) {

        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String toString() {

        final String info =
                "car name = " + name
                        + " *** body = " + body
                        + " *** color = " + color;
        return info;
    }
}
```

**3) Класс VolvoBuilder, который наследуется от BaseCarBuilder.**

```
public class VolvoBuilder extends BaseCarBuilder {

    public VolvoBuilder() {
        car = new Car("Volvo");
    }

    @Override
    public void buildBody() {
        car.setBody(Car.LIMOUSINE);
    }

    @Override
    public void buildColor() {
        car.setColor(Car.WHITE);
    }
}
```

**4) Директор**

```
public class Director {

    private BaseCarBuilder baseCarBuilder;

    public Director(BaseCarBuilder baseCarBuilder) {

        this.baseCarBuilder = baseCarBuilder;
    }

    public void buildNewCar() {

        this.baseCarBuilder.buildBody();
        this.baseCarBuilder.buildColor();
    }
}
```

**5) Клиент**

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        VolvoBuilder volvoBuilder = new VolvoBuilder();
        Director director = new Director(volvoBuilder);
        director.buildNewCar();
        System.err.println(volvoBuilder.getCar().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это древний code review запрос без контекста

Answer (score 5):

Почти хорошо.

```
public abstract class BaseCarBuilder {

    // Если формально следовать паттерну Builder по Gang of Four
    // (http://goo.gl/rX9gMN), то этого члена класса (и метода getCar) здесь
    // быть не должно. В их варианте паттерна 'getResult' является членом
    // *конкретного* экземпляра ConcreteBuilder, но не является членом
    // интерфейса Builder. Понятно, почему такое решение лучше: класс
    // Director не использует этот метод для создания объекта, а результат
    // все равно спрашивается у ConcreteBuilder. Поэтому лично я перенес бы
    // эту штуку отсюда в VolvoBuilder. В реализации http://goo.gl/KRk1L
    // метод 'getHouse', кстати, есть и в интерфейсе Builder, и в Director,
    // но это можно оставить на совести автора. Если уж делаем по GoF, то
    // стоит следовать их варианту.

    protected Car car;

    public abstract void buildBody();

    public abstract void buildColor();

    public Car getCar() {
       return car;
    }

   }

public class Car {

    // Это очередной косяк реализации http://goo.gl/KRk1L, который
    // просочился в ваш вариант. Для этой проблемы даже есть специальное
    // название ("Stringly typed" — http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped ).
    // Такой код усложняет рефакторинг (попробуйте правильно переименовать
    // RED -> BLUE с помощью встроенных средств вашей IDE) и не защищает от
    // ошибок типа car.setBody("COBROALET"). Используйте enum.

    // В Java предпочтительным порядком является 'static final':
    // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1

    public final static String RED = "RED";
    public final static String BLACK = "BLACK";
    public final static String WHITE = "WHITE";
    public final static String SEDAN = "SEDAN";
    public final static String CABRIOLET = "CABRIOLET";
    public final static String LIMOUSINE = "LIMOUSINE";

    ...

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    // Несмотря на то, что результат метода 'toString' для произвольного
    // класса формально может быть каким угодно, обычно имеет смысл
    // следовать common guidelines. Ваш метод использует какую-то вариацию
    // кастомного стиля форматирования, которая может сильно выбиваться из
    // общего стиля, например, при просмотре в IDE. См. http://goo.gl/1L3C7P
    // и http://goo.gl/bZ12E7

    // Еще вы забыли @Override.

    public String toString() {

        final String info =
                "car name = " + name
                        + " *** body = " + body
                        + " *** color = " + color;
        return info;
    }
}

public class VolvoBuilder extends BaseCarBuilder {

    public VolvoBuilder() {
        car = new Car("Volvo");
    }

    @Override
    public void buildBody() {
        car.setBody(Car.LIMOUSINE);
    }

    @Override
    public void buildColor() {
        car.setColor(Car.WHITE);
    }
}

// Вкусовщина, но я бы использовал название CarBuilderDirector, иначе, если
// в том же самом namespace будет несколько director'ов, то вы не сможете
// их различить без переименования.

public class Director {

    // ... final?
    private BaseCarBuilder baseCarBuilder;

    public Director(BaseCarBuilder baseCarBuilder) {

        this.baseCarBuilder = baseCarBuilder;
    }

    // По GoF Builder этот метод должен называться 'construct'.
    public void buildNewCar() {

        this.baseCarBuilder.buildBody();
        this.baseCarBuilder.buildColor();
    }
}

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // В качестве упражнения рекомендую вам покрыть этот код тестами.
        // Если хотите, можете объединить добавление тестов с исправлением
        // изложенных здесь замечаний и выслать reroll#3, который я (мы?) с
        // радостью посмотрю(им).

        VolvoBuilder volvoBuilder = new VolvoBuilder();
        Director director = new Director(volvoBuilder);
        director.buildNewCar();
        System.err.println(volvoBuilder.getCar().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо, что помогаете мне !!! Я искренне Вам благодарен.
Я только недавно начал учиться программировать, если допускаю простые или тупые ошибки, извините меня. Надеюсь стану программировать лучше!

Comment: @Иван_Белозеров0011 Нет тупых ошибок, есть только нежелание их исправлять и делать хорошо. Можете выкладывать решения других задач (желательно, чуть менее абстрактных) с каким-нибудь хитрым тэгом типа `code-review`.

Comment: Исправленный вариант паттерна, покрытый тестами высылать Вам как ссылку на GitHub или использовать какой-либо файл_обменник ?

Comment: @Иван_Белозеров0011

- На ваше усмотрение, но я бы оформлял каждую законченную версию как отдельный вопрос. Я думаю, что здесь найдется достаточное количество человек, кроме меня, которые смогут указать вам на ваши ошибки.

- Можете использовать какой-нибудь naming convention в именах вопросов, например, [как делают в git-dev](http://goo.gl/zkOIUx). То есть, ваши текущие два вопроса можно переименовать в "Реализация паттерна Builder V1" и "Реализация паттерна Builder V2", прилепить в каждый из них тэг `code-review` и сделать ссылку с версии 2 на версию 1 в тексте вопроса. Аналогично для V3.

Comment: Вышла в свет третья реализация паттерна Builder c Junit тестами.
Ссылка: http://clck.ru/8pknj